# Finding an Entry in a Join Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Okay, this shouldn't be too bad but I'm struggling. Essentially I have a `has_many :through` association involving a `user` model, a `collective` model, and a `membership` model (the join table). My membership model has 4 fields: id, user_id, collective_id, and a bool called owner. What I am trying to do is test if the `current_user` is an owner of collective on the collective's show page. Unfortunately when I try to do this I get an "undefined method 'owner'" error.

It's also worth mentioning that I've already made sure the membership associations are properly created when a user is added to a group so I don't think the association is the problem.

**Collective's show.html.erb**

```
<% if @collective.memberships.where(:user_id => current_user.id).owner? %>
    <%= link_to '(Add User)', '#' %>
<% end %>
```

**Collective Controller**

```
def show
    @collective = Collective.find(params[:id])
end
```

**Membership Model**

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :collective

    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :collective_id, presence: true
    validates :owner, presence: true    
end
```

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling an instance method on an `ActiveRecord::Relation` array object.

Add `first` to receive a single object `Membership`:

```
@collective.memberships.where(:user_id => current_user.id).first.owner?
```

---

Another way to do it is using [`exists?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/exists%3F/class)

```
@collective.memberships.exists?(user_id: current_user.id, owner: true)
```

Comment: Ah I see. Fantastic! I had a feeling there was a smoother way to do this.

Comment: Great, take a look at `exists?` docs (its not limited to join models) :)